# Solving a specific case of Abel's differential equation of the second kind

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'd really like to solve this equation:

$$y \frac{dy}{dx} = -y - 2x^2(1-x)$$

This equation cropped up in my research, so I don't know whether a solution is even possible.  I tried solving it, but I got nowhere.

Please let me know if you:
1) Know how to solve it
2) Can suggest a possible method for solving it
3) Know that it is not possible to solve it

Thank you!

---

Edit:  In the process of formulating this equation originally, I missed a sign (embarrasing, so sorry!).   I've changed the sign that I missed and now a particular solution seems to be just:

$$y(x) = x^2 - x$$

So, from my point of view, this (new) problem is now partly solved.   If anyone wants to see the incorrect equation for fun, I'm reprinting it here:

$$y \frac{dy}{dx} = y - 2x^2(1-x)$$

As @JJacquelin points out in the comments, a particular solution to this is

$$y(x) = x- x^2$$

Again, my apologies for initially posting the incorrect equation.

---

Edit 2

As it turns out, the particular solution satisfies my initial condition $y(0)=0$, so it solves this problem for my current purposes.  However, I am still curious as to whether a general solution is possible, so I will leave the question open.  I also wonder whether this particular solution is the only one to satisfy my initial condition, or whether there are others.

Comment: I doubt that the general solution could be expressed on closed form. Eventually analytical solving could br possible for some initial condition. What is the initial condition ? By the way, a particular solution is $y=x-x^2$.

Comment: @JJacquelin -- thank you!   The particular soln may be what I need.

Comment: Although this ODE highly relates to http://science.fire.ustc.edu.cn/download/download1/book%5Cmathematics%5CHandbook%20of%20Exact%20Solutions%20for%20Ordinary%20Differential%20EquationsSecond%20Edition%5Cc2972_fm.pdf#page=133, the link only claims the trivial particular solution.

Comment: I find some interesting properties in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754427 and may be suitable to apply on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer to the question, but it's too long for a comment, and I just want to note a typical approach for solving ODE's which can ***not*** be used in this case. This doesn't mean that there doesn't exist any method to solve it -- this just means that this common method does not work.

Rewriting the equation as $$y \frac{dy}{dx} + y = -2x^2(1-x) $$ we see that this is ***not*** a linear ODE.

If we tried to write the LHS as a differential operator, we would see that it has the form

$$ M  y , \quad \text{where} \quad M = y D + y$$

We see that the coefficient of the first derivative $D$ is ***not*** a function of $x$, but a function of $y$. Therefore the differential operator $M$ for this equation is ***not*** a linear operator, and the standard methods which apply to linear ODE's do not apply.

Therefore, if you want to find a solution to the equation, it will have to be a method for solving (certain classes of) ***nonlinear*** ODE's.

I know this does not solve your problem, but hopefully will prevent you from pursuing unnecessary dead-ends.

Comment: Thank you @Chill2Macht!  I think this is a good way of showing/explaining why this particular problem is so difficult.   You are right that to find a general solution, I would need to use methods for nonlinear ODEs.  This whole problem has me wondering whether these methods are organized by any higher framework or theory.   Do you know?   It seems like each kind of problem has its own little trick;  is there anything deeper?

Comment: @EPH The world of nonlinear ODEs is not my area of expertise. I would say that, to the best of my knowledge, it somewhat resembles the study of PDEs, in that there is less emphasis on finding explicit/closed-form solutions, and more emphasis on either (1) proving existence results using tools like functional analysis and (2) numerical techniques for calculating approximations to solutions which have been shown to exist. See, for example, the field of nonlinear dynamics, of which Strogatz's book is the most famous. E.g. see http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~olver/am_/odz.pdf

Comment: To check for the existence of a solution, the first thing you want to try is Picard-Lindelof https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem  To get your ODE into the form of the Picard-Lindelof theorem, you would have to divide by y, i.e. ignore possible solutions where $y(x) = 0$ at any point. But I'm not sure whether the resulting function $f(x, y(x))$ would be Lipschitz continuous or not.